# PHP sum of numbers by keeping leading zeros

Tags: php, laravel

I have some increment of invoice numbers, where there is Prefix and Counter,
Say Prefix is `INV-` and Counter is started with `001`.

Below is code used in Laravel to get the next Invoice number automatically,

```
        $lastInv = explode('-', $record->invoice_number); //Gets record and split number

        $nextInv = $settings->invoice_number_prefix.'-'. ($lastInv[1] + 1);
```

In this case, there are two records in DB with INV-001, INV-002, But with the above code, I am getting `$nextInv` as `INV-3`

How can I generate next invoice as `INV-003`

thank you,

Comment: Have a look to [printf()](https://php.net/printf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `str_pad` to flll `0` with perfix

like this

```php
$lastInv = explode('-', $record->invoice_number); //Gets record and split number
$number = str_pad($lastInv[1] + 1,3,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
$nextInv = $settings->invoice_number_prefix.'-'. $number;
```

> **NOTE** here `str_pad('',3,'0','')`  here 3 is the number with will fill with zero so you can adjust based on your need

ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php